# regex: find pattern if no preceding asterix, and ignoring everything inside curly brackets

Tags: regex

I need to identify records/strings that match the following specifications: 
the occurence of the substring `"}* foo"` when there is not any
other asterisk before this one, ignoring anything that is
inside curly brackets `(possibly multiple and/or nested)`.

```
abc 123 {def * 456} ghj {klm* 789 { nop*0}}* foo bar
```

should be found

```
abc 123 {def * 456} ghj* {klm* 789 { nop*0>}}* foo bar
```

should not be found

I tried it with a lookahead regex but did not even come close to a solution. 
Your help is very appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Please explain your question in details so that we can help you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?:[^*]*{[^}]*})*[^*]*}\* foo
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dM8dZ6/3)

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response and working solution!